# what is this floor reflective shading texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders, reflection

what is ths reflective, glossy, smooth white texture?
Kindly help me answer steps to create this white reflective texture

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the texture with the Playstation Logo? If yes, I think nobody can tell you but you can try to recreate it if the picture would be better in quality.

Comment: Hi, I mean the white floor that can reflect object